# Square brackets in MySQL LIKE

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like

I have a table (let's call it A) with a text field called `references_int` which has numerous values. One example is `'internal\reference[111]'`.

If I do

```
SELECT * 
FROM A 
WHERE references_int LIKE 'internal\\reference[111]'
```

it will return zero rows. But if I replace `LIKE` with `=` it works.

I use a framework that simplifies find queries, but it uses `LIKE`.. Is there a way for it to work?

No idea if it's a bug or a feature.

Thanks!

Comment: I've checked the binary value of the field and it matches (if I do hex(value) = hex(column)). There are only ASCII chars in stored in the field.

Answer (score 5):

Escape each `\`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM A 
WHERE references_int LIKE 'internal\\\\reference[111]'
```

By default, if you don't specify an `ESCAPE` character to `LIKE`, `\` is assumed, as per the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like). An alternative is to use a different `ESCAPE` character:

```
SELECT * 
FROM A 
WHERE 'internalrefer\\ence[111]' LIKE 'internalrefer\\ence[111]' ESCAPE '#'
```

Comment: +1. As [the doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) explains, "To search for '`\ `', specify it as '`\\\\ `'".